# Keras LSTM expects 3 dimensions when I give it 2, but 4 dimensions when I give it 3

Tags: keras, lstm

This gives me an error, telling me it expected 3 dimensions but got 2:

input_layer = Input(shape=(None, 1000000))

```python
lstm_1 = LSTM(500, dropout=.2, recurrent_dropout=.2)(input_layer)
```

Either of these gives me an error, telling me it expected 4 dimensions but got 3:

```python
input_layer = Input(shape=(None, 1000000, None))

input_layer = Input(shape=(None, None, 1000000))
```

Comment: The problem is your data. LSTM's need 3D data. (PS: are you sure you've got a million features instead of a million steps?)

Comment: `Input(shape=(None,1000000))` has 3 dimensions (batch size is hidden).

Answer (score 1):

The input `shape` parameter doesn't take into account the **batch size**, so really giving `shape=(None, 1000)` is expecting `(batch_size, None, 100)` and it becomes 3 dimensional. As a result you need to feed data of shape (samples, timesteps, features), so a 3D data input for `fit` function.